# Web app that lets users upload a video

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am tryin to build a web app on ruby on rails and I can't figure out where to find the code for letting users log in and upload their video to the app wall. Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), most tutorials will guide you through letting users upload photos, but CW can manage practically any type of file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial to follow http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder .

It depends on your deployment platform. If you are using Heroku (which has a 30 second http request timeout) then I would suggest implementing Uploadify or Carrierwave-direct.

If they are small videos then just use CarrierWave like suggested above, use Amazon S3 for storage and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for your user authentication.